# How to pass static data from one component to another in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a plans component where I define the plan type, and I redirect to sign up component. I want to be able to show the plan type that the user has chosen, in my signup component?

I am trying to update the state like this:

```
 export default class Plans extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          planType: '',

    };
     }

     render() {
       return (
    <div>

          <div className="billing_freq">Billed Monthly</div>
          <form action="pro-invitation" method="post"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="plan_type" value="monthly_pro" /> //I want to show this in signup
            <div className="select_btn">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" onClick={() => this.setState({planType: "monthly_pro"})} value="Invitation only" />
            </div>
          </form>


Signup: // a separate component
      <label className="container"><span className="plan_name"></span> //PLAN TYPE HERE
  </label>


class App extends Component {

 render () {
    return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">

    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/plans' component={Plans} />   
      <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />
    </Switch>

  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Dont really got what you want to achieve, but if you want to show the value you've changed, you can access it via this.state.planType

Comment: and if the Signup component is nested in Plans you can pass the planType via props for example: <Signup planType={this.state.planType} />, and in Singup component acces it {this.props.planType}

Comment: They are separate components. I have multiple inputs with different plan types. Basically, when a user clicks on a plan type I want to send the plan type to the sign up component so the user can see which plan type they have chosen. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: So I wrote you. You have Plans component and when you change the planType via setState, pass the new value as a prop to Singup component. In Signup component use this planType (as a prop) and display in this span or label, do you get me?

Comment: You can write an answer with an explanation.

Comment: Yeah with your complete answer you think that the signup is nested even though I told you it's not. Good luck to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you going to render Signup Component?

If from the routing, then there will be different way to achieve it and if you're using as a child component the pass as props like this -

```
<SignUp planType={this.state.planType} />
```

and access in Signup component as

```
<label className="container"><span className="plan_name"></span>{this.props.planType}
</label>
```

Comment: I edited my question, you can see how I am rendering it there.

Comment: You can make route as <Route exact path='/signup/:type' component={Signup} />
and pass while routing and you will get data in routes props.

Comment: Can you send some example link on how I can do it? Thank you

Comment: Also I just realized my route when I go to signup is this: http://localhost:3000/signup?plan_type=monthly_startup&submit=Try+for+free

Answer (score 0):

You want to give your planType state to the child component.

You can do this by doing this:

```
<Signup planType={this.state.planType} />
```

To use this in your child component use the props that you received from the parent, which is your planType state.

```
<label className="container"><span className="plan_name"></span>{this.props.planType}</label>
```